# Stuck on thumbnails - MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I'm trying to see full page view in MS Word (MS Subscription apps for Enterprise version) but it's grayed out under the View menu and only Thumbnails is available.

Comment: Try going to menu *File > Options >Display* and verify that "Show white space between pages in Print Layout View" is checked.

Comment: Yes, checked... no change.